# How to get two values from one table in ms access

Tags: microsoft-access

I want to know that How can I get two values from a table in ms access.

1. I have a CustomersTable, which contain CustomerId,Name,Phone,Address.... , Rate.
   (I am adding Rate in this table because rate varies for every customer).
2. I have another table SaleTable which contain  CustomerId, NumberOfItems, TotalPrice.
3. I want to add an entry in SaleTable. How can I retrieve two values from CustomerTable? CustomerId and Rate (because TotalPrice = NumberOfItems *  Rate).

For SaleTable I can get SaleTalbe.CustomerId from CustomerTalbe.CustomerId. but can I also get CustomerTable.Rate from CustomerTable by providing customerId only once??

Comment: Are you familiar with SQL? Or more comfortable using the query wizards and table wizards? There are a few ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Oh, almost forgot, VERY IMPT, what is Rate? At first glance, Rate seemed like "Rate of Pay", or more like "flat shipping Rate"? Curios as the context of this because it could influence the integrity of your tables. And are you familiar with Foreign Key?

Answer (score 2):

**Tables:**

- customers
- sales

**Queries:**

- QueryCustomerRateItems

   -- with expressions evaluating two tables

The easiest way is to create a query. Start an empty query. Drag tables "cusotmers" and "sales" into the query.

**Note:** In a *QUERY* - Take note where the primary key is and isn't. Take note on the two leftmost columns. The other columns are 'Expressions' using 'dot' association as follows. The format is:

```
 MyNameAsThisTitle: [table1.Field2]*[table2.Field4]
```

**The desired result is in the final image:** *If you understand relationships between tables, queries, and sums, then take a peek at the final image(10). If you look at the final image and don't understand how it works, or why, then step through the images in order from 1-to-10.*

---

Here is the procedure. Examine each screenshot to get a grasp how each step transforms your data:

---

**SALES**

(1)
[image: Sales Table]

---

**CUSTOMERS**

(2)
[image: Customers Table]

---

**Setting Up the QUERY: Note the "Expressions"**

(3)
[image: Setting Up the Query]

---

**Follow the flow and how it changes the data**

(4)
[image]

---

(5) 

click the image to get a good look at the expressions
[image]

---

(6)
[image]

---

(7)

Sum The desired FIELD! Un-Check data that doesn't make sense on the summation
[image]

---

(8)

Result of image-7 above in each "item"
[image]

---

(9)
[image]

---

(10)

Desired result: Summation of Cost wrt Rate. Reveals total cost related to customerID.
[image]

Comment: Newer seen someone explain in this detail. Nice

Answer (score 0):

select CustomerTable.field1,CustomerTable.field2,SaleTable.field1,SaleTable.field2 from CustomerTable,Sales table where SaleTable.CustomerId=CustomerTable.CustomerId and SaleTable.CustomerID=23423;

You can switch to an SQL mode/view and enter something like the above.  You can obviously name any columns you want in the first part.